# Approximation of Exponentially and Normally Distributed Probabilities

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution, word-problem

**PROBLEM**

> A company uses a portable high-intensity flashlight: Batteries and bulbs burn out quickly.

- The lifetime of batteries has Exponential Distribution with mean $10$ hours.
- The bulbs have lifetimes that are Normally Distributed with mean $32$ and standard deviation $5$.

Assume batteries and bulbs are randomly sampled. Find the probabilities for the following events:
*[Where appropriate you may approximate probabilities]*

- A battery lasts over $11$ hours.
- A sample of $20$ batteries has a sample mean over $11$ hours.
- A sample of $200$ batteries has a sample mean over $11$ hours.

I am not sure how to solve these questions because I've only learned approximating with the normal distribution to the binomial. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got a 0 probability for a) so I think there must've been something wrong in the calculation there, I put in 1-pexp(11,10) into R. However, with b) and c) I'm not sure how to solve it with the sample numbers in there.

Comment: In R function `pexp` the second argument is the _rate_, not the mean. So use `1/10`. // Since you're using R, I'll mention that sums and averages of exponential samples have _gamma_ distributions; have you studied that? In R, the 3rd argument of `pgamma` is also _rate_ $\lambda = 1/\beta,$ where $\beta$ is scale parameter.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot about that thanks, haven't taken stats in a little bit as you can probably tell.

Comment: Suggest you [_look at this_](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155296/distribution-of-the-sample-mean-of-a-exponential). Including the answer and the Wikipedia ref.

Comment: Sorry, there's an error in that link, see my Answer to (b). I have posted a correction note at the link. Please doublecheck.

Comment: BTW, using an exponential distribution to model battery life seems quite strange. In reliability theory, the no-memory property of the exponential dist'n is sometimes phrased as "Used is as good as new." For any battery I know of, used is _not_ as good as new.

Answer (score 0):

Because the link that I provided in a Comment has incorrect information, 
I am posting this Answer to (b).

You have $n = 20$ observations from $\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda = 1/10),$
and you seek $P(\bar X > 11).$

The individual observations have $\mu =E(X_i) = 1/\lambda = 10,$ 
variance $\sigma^2 = 1/\lambda^2 = 100,$ and SD $\sigma = 1/\lambda.$

The mean of $n = 20$ such observations has $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(n,n\lambda).$ Hence $E(\bar X) = \frac{n}{n\lambda} = \frac{1}{\lambda} = 10,$
variance $V(\bar X) = \frac{1}{n\lambda^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} = 
\frac{100}{20} = 5,$
and $SD(\bar X) = \frac{1}{\lambda\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = 
\frac{10}{\sqrt{20}} =
\sqrt{5} = 2.2361.$

These results can be derived using moment generating functions and
standard formulas for means and variances of random variables.
Hence $P(\bar X > 11) = 0.306027,$ as computed in R statistical software below:

```
n = 20;  lam = 0.1;  1 - pgamma(11, n, n*lam)
## 0.306027
```

Of course, part (c) can be done similarly in R. Also, in (c) a normal approximation
based on $n=200$ is reasonably accurate.

```
n = 200; lam = .1;  mu = 1/lam;  sg = 1/(lam*sqrt(n))
1 - pgamma(11, n, n*lam)
## 0.08180569                # exact
1 - pnorm(11,  mu, sg)
## 0.0786496                 # norm aprx
```

---

*Note:* Just as a 'reality check', when claiming an error elsewhere, I took a
million samples of size $n = 20$ from $\mathsf{Exp}(rate = \lambda = 0.1)$
and found the corresponding million averages with the following results,
agreeing with the theoretical results for (b) above, within the margin of sampling error.

```
 a = replicate(10^6, mean(rexp(20, .1)))
 mean(a > 11)     
 ## 0.306304       # aprx P(Avg > 11) = 0.306027
 mean(a);  sd(a)
 ## 9.99888        # aprx 10
 ## 2.236212       # aprx sqrt(5)
```

Below is a histogram of the one million sample means along with the
density function of $\mathsf{Gamma}(20, 2).$

[image]