# How to design this two sample exponential distribution test?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Given independent random samples $(X_1,...,X_m)$ and $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$, respectively, from the following distributions of $X$ and $Y: X \sim \lambda_1 \exp (-\lambda_1 x) I(x >0)$, and $Y \sim \lambda_2 \exp (-\lambda_2 y) I(y >0)$. Consider the problem of testing the null hypothesis $H_0:\lambda_1=\lambda_2 $ against the alternative: $H_1:\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 $.

a. Formulate the underlying testing problem as that of testing one of the parameters in a multiparameter exponential family, having expressed the family explicitly in terms of all the parameters and the corresponding statistics.

b. Give the formula of the UMPU test at level $\alpha$, in its conditional form, involving these statistics.

c. Describe how this test can be stated equivalently as an unconditional test. What are the ultimate test statistic and the rejection region (in terms of a known distribution)?

Some examples of the similar question:

Say $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $X \sim Bin(m, p_1), Y\sim Bin(n , p_2)$.We want to test

$$H_0: p_1=p_2 \text{against} H_1: p_1>p_2,$$

Then $(X,Y)\sim f_{\theta_1,\theta_2} (x,y)=e^{\theta_1 T_1 + \theta_2 T_2-A(\theta_1,\theta_2 )}h(x,y)$

with $\theta_1=\log \frac{p_1 (1-p_2)}{p_2 (1-p_1)}, T_1=X, \theta_2=\log \frac{p_2}{1-p_2}, T_2=X+Y$

$$H_0: \theta_1=0 \text{ against } H_1: \theta_1>0.$$

The UMPU test

$ \phi_0 (T_1,T_2) = \begin{cases} 1 ,  \text{if} T_1 > c(T_2) \\
      \psi(T_2) ,  \text{if} T_1=c(T_2) \\
0, \text{if} T_1<c(T_2) \end{cases}$

where $c(T_2)$ and $\psi(T_2)$ are such that $E_{\theta_1=0} (\phi_0 (T_1, T_2) | T_2)=\alpha$.

Since the conditional distribution $T_1=X$ given $T_2=X+Y=t_2$ is

$$P(X=x | X+Y=t_2)=\frac{{m\choose x}{n \choose t_2-x} }{m+n \choose t_2}$$

$c(t_2)$ and $\psi(t_2)$ are such that

$$\sum\limits_{x > c(t_2)}  {m\choose x} {n \choose t_2-x}+ \psi(t_2) {m \choose c(t_2) } {n \choose t_2-c(t_2)}={m+n \choose t_2}\alpha$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I provided the final solution. Hope you can show how it can be obtained following the steps you are given.

Considering that (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877178/1231520))

$$\frac{\lambda_1 \bar{X}}{\lambda_2 \bar{Y}}=\frac{\frac{2 \lambda_1 m \bar{X}}{2m}}{\frac{2 \lambda_2 m \bar{Y}}{2n}} \sim \frac{\frac{\chi^2_{2m}}{2m}}{\frac{\chi^2_{2n}}{2n}} \sim F_{2m,2n}$$

for $$\color{blue}{H_0: \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}= \theta}$$

you can use the test with the following test statistic: $$\color{blue}{T = \theta \frac {\bar{X}}{\bar{Y}}}$$

and critical region:

$$\color{blue}{C= \mathbb R \setminus (f_{(2m,2n), 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}, f_{(2m,2n), \frac{\alpha}{2}})}$$

where $\alpha$ is the significance level of the test. Note that $f_{(2m,2n), 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \frac{1}{f_{(2n,2m), \frac{\alpha}{2}}} $.

Comment: Thank you. But what is the answer for part a? I don't know how to write multiparameter exponential family here.

Comment: @Jonathen please add more details to your question or provide a source in which the terms conditionaltest, multiparameter exponential family and UMPU are clearly defined. Then, I may be able to help more.

Comment: I add a similar question here.

Comment: Could you help me a similar question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877528/design-two-independent-normal-samples-to-test-h-0-mu-1-mu-2

Comment: @Jonathen I can provide the required test (not sure if it is useful for you), but I have not understood how the procedure works yet and why it results in the most powerfull test.

Comment: yes, that will be useful for me. Thank you!